# running JBoss-3.2.1 in eclipse 3.5.2

Tags: eclipse, jboss

When I try to run from `eclipse 3.5.2` a "clean" version of `JBoss 3.2.1 AS` downloaded from it's homepage I get an error message:

> JBossTools: JBoss 3.2 Runtime - MOCK:
>   invalid option -- b

I am using `default` configuration.

When I launch the same server from console everything runs just fine.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: JBoss 3.2 is *6 years old*.... do you really want to be using that?

Comment: @skaffman: Well, I don't have a choice. I am developing an existing JEE application and it's to big to migrate it to newer server version :/

Answer (score 1):

Jboss 3 is really old, I'd stay away from it if at all possible.

Your error looks to me like eclipse is trying to pass an option that isn't recognized by your version of JBoss.  See above.

If you really have to use jboss 3, then you might need to make sure the other software in your toolchain is of the same vintage.  Maybe try Eclipse 2.1?